# go get and AzureDevOps authentication not working

Tags: go, azure-devops, goland

I am desperately trying to figure out why a `go get` command from a package residing inside a Git repo on AzureDevOps does not work.

Both golang projects (the project where the package resides as well as the consumer trying to import it) are located inside the same AzureDevOps project.
I am attempting to import a package from the one into the other but alas with no avail.

I followed the instructions found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/go-get?view=azure-devops

I have created a PAT and tested that I am able to clone the repo from where I want to import the package from, and that works fine.

```
git clone https://me:78rt5u89dg635ef4fb30e4b0229e4329756986416673b4e331ag@dev.azure.com/my-comp/my-proj/_git/k8s-team-operator
```

So I have in my mind (maybe incorrectly so) made the assumption that the PAT is able to authenticate correctly. That said, I unfortunately have to use cntlm proxy to get to the outside, but this works well in general.

In my golang project inside the terminal I have set : `export GOPRIVATE=dev.azure.com`

In my GitConfig file located at location ~/.gitconfig  I have  set the following values:

```
# This is Git's per-user configuration file.
[user]
        email = me@my-comp.com
        name = Morné Kruger

[core]
        editor = vi

[url https://me:78rt5u89dg635ef4fb30e4b0229e4329756986416673b4e331a@dev.azure.com/my-comp/my-proj/_git/k8s-team-operator]
    insteadOf = https://dev.azure.com/my-comp/my-proj/_git/k8s-team-operator
```

I then run the go get command with the verbose flag, and then get the following less positive response:

```
me@focalfossa:~/dev/my-comp/repos/k8s-teamapi-functions$ go get -x dev.azure.com/my-comp/my-proj/_git/k8s-team-operator.git
# get https://dev.azure.com/my-comp/my-proj/_git?go-get=1
# get https://dev.azure.com/?go-get=1
# get https://dev.azure.com/my-comp?go-get=1
cd .
git ls-remote https://dev.azure.com/my-comp/my-proj/_git/k8s-team-operator
# get https://dev.azure.com/my-comp/my-proj?go-get=1
cd .
git ls-remote git+ssh://dev.azure.com/my-comp/my-proj/_git/k8s-team-operator
# get https://dev.azure.com/?go-get=1: 403 Forbidden (0.274s)
# get https://dev.azure.com/my-comp/my-proj?go-get=1: 203 Non-Authoritative Information (0.307s)
# get https://dev.azure.com/my-comp?go-get=1: 203 Non-Authoritative Information (0.308s)
# get https://dev.azure.com/my-comp/my-proj/_git?go-get=1: 203 Non-Authoritative Information (0.311s)
cd .
git ls-remote ssh://dev.azure.com/my-comp/my-proj/_git/k8s-team-operator
mkdir -p /home/me/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs # git3 git://dev.azure.com/my-comp/my-proj/_git/k8s-team-operator
# lock /home/me/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/540338d35ef4fb30e4b0229e4329756986416673b4e3318516900fca1efcee17.lock# /home/me/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/540338d35ef4fb485763tg30417801e630216673b4e3318516900fca1efcee17 for git3 git://dev.azure.com/my-comp/my-proj/_git/k8s-team-operator
cd /home/me/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/540338d35ef4fb30e4b02906874yh25630216673b4e3318516900fca1efcee17; git ls-remote -q origin
2.083s # cd /home/me/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/540338d35ef49059y87e329e417801e630216673b4e3318516900fca1efcee17; git ls-remote -q origin
go get: module dev.azure.com/my-comp/my-proj/_git/k8s-team-operator.git: git ls-remote -q origin in /home/me/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/540338d35ef4fb30e4b022125f7y879430216673b4e3318516900fca1efcee17: exit status 128:
        fatal: unable to connect to dev.azure.com:
        dev.azure.com[0: 13.107.42.20]: errno=Connection refused
        dev.azure.com[1: 2620:1ec:21::20]: errno=Network is unreachable
```

Versions:
go1.16.5 linux/amd64
Ubuntu 20.04
GoLand 2021.1.2
git version 2.25.1

I would greatly appreciate any tips or troubleshooting ideas that could point out the error in my ways!